# How to get all QPushButton of a specific layout

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qpushbutton

I would like to know how to get all QPushButtons of a specific Layout.

Here is my code (doesn't work)

```
QList<QPushButton *> step2PButtons = findChildren<QPushButton *>(step2Layout);
for (auto *button: step2PButtons )
    button->setEnabled(false);
```

I have the following error :

```
no matching function for call to 'MainWindow::findChildren(QVBoxLayout*&)'
```

I can get all the elements of my interface, but i cannot get elements of a specific layout.

Thanks for helping

Comment: What is the type of `step2Layout` exactly?

Comment: It is a QVBoxLayout

Comment: Is it a pointer or not?

Comment: Honestly I don't know.. I created it with QtDesigner..

Comment: Then it's a pointer, most likely. Try the solution I suggested down there.

Comment: Ok thanks I will kow it for later ! I will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
QList<QPushButton*> step2PButtons = step2Layout->findChildren<QPushButton*>();
for(auto it = step2PButtons.begin(); it != step2PButtons.end(); ++it)
    (*it)->setEnabled(false);
```

I'm guessing `step2Layout` is a pointer to a `QVBoxLayout` object.

It's a member function of `QObject`, which `step2Layout` is derived from. You're calling it from `QMainWindow`, and that's why you're getting all Window buttons.

Comment: @LucasPierrat How about this one, now?

Comment: @LucasPierrat At this point, you have to debug this further yourself. I can't debug for you here. The function `findChildren()` is working, but you have to track what children it's finding. Check the size of the list, and check the names of the members and their types. Spend some time debugging the issue.

Comment: Try `findChildren` directly on the widget instead the layout.

Comment: Yes of course I understand ! I will find the problem. Thanks for your help

Comment: @cbuchart Actually it looks like this is what he was doing in the beginning. Notice the code he posted in the question.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist, yes, but the first attempt was passing a `QVBoxLayout` as argument, which is not defined. I mean to try your solution but on the widget directly.

Comment: @cbuchart I'm guessing because he said in his question "I can get all the elements of my interface".

Answer (score 0):

The Quantum Physicist's answer is correct but one small detail is missing: when you create a layout with Qt Designer, if you look at the generated code you will see that it creates a "hidden" QWidget, parent to the layout:

```
QWidget *verticalLayoutWidget;
QVBoxLayout *verticalLayout;
[...]
verticalLayoutWidget = new QWidget(centralWidget);
```

Then the button that you think is child of the layout is actually not, it is child of this hidden widget.

```
pushButton = new QPushButton(verticalLayoutWidget);
```

If you replace `step2Layout->findChildren<QPushButton*>();` by `step2Layout->parentWidget()->findChildren<QPushButton*>();` you should get the buttons that are in your layout and can process them in the loop.